# Adding two value to WP custom fields

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom-field applied to specific posts, but I want to add two values to one field. How do I do that from the admin side?

[image]

CSS

```
.post-1 {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-position: left center;
  float: left;
}
```

I want to add '.bgAlign' class to the value of ExtraCSS. I tried just adding it but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: can you explain the issue in further details

Comment: You can try two value by separate space (post-1 post-2) in custom field and write two different css in css ..i have not tried it ..but it should work..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple append your class after `post-1` with comma separator. It would be look like `post-1,bgAlign,one-more-class`. 
Use this to output

```
<?php global $post; ?>
<div class="<?php echo str_replace(',', ' ', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ExtraCSS', true)); ?>"></div>
```

Changing commas with spaces